# Make Slack API buttons "do something"

Tags: python, url, post, flask, slack-api

Edit: Since I asked this question I have created a ngrok URL to receive the Slack POST when the user his the button.

However, every time I press the button I get this: `"POST / HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

I am using a local Flask URL, code below:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/payload', methods=['POST'])
def incoming_slack_message():
    req = request.get_json(Force=True)
    info = request.form['channel_id']
    print(req)
    print(info)
    print('did it work???')
    return 'action successful'


@app.route('/slack/blocks', methods=['POST'])
def incoming_slack_options():
    req = request.get_json(Force=True)
    info = request.form['payload']
    print(req)
    print(info)
    print('Did it work here??')
    return 'ok'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=3000, debug = True)
```

I have read that I need to include a callback_id in the block but whenever I do I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`
This is the block I am using less the callback_id

`{
    "type": "section",
    "text": {
        "type": "mrkdwn",
        "text": "Once your machine is selected, click here."
    },
    "accessory": {
        "type": "button",
        "text": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "Change",
        },
        "value": "click_me_123",
        "action_id": "button"
    }
}`

I am SURE something is wrong in my flask code as I know little to nothing about Flask. I don't think there's anything wrong with my Slack Block but I still feel there should be a callback_id. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got the button to generate a response! The Flask code is as follows

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response, jsonify
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def resp():
    data = request.json
    button_info = request.form['payload']
    webhook_url = 'webhook from slack'
    slack_data = { 'text': "How can I help you?"}
    response = requests.post(
    webhook_url, data=json.dumps(slack_data),
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    )
    return(jsonify(data), print(button_info))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=3000, debug = True)
```

The button_info will print out all the data.
I'm sure I can get rid of some of these line/imports and it will still work but this will get the job done!

*** This code is in conjunction with a ngrok public URL for the local web server.

`brew cask install ngrok` followed by

`ngrok http 3000` to match the 3000 port in my code

The`webhook_url` is from the slack API website.